# evento onbeforeunload

Tags: javascript, eventos, input

Tengo el siguiente código:

HTML:

```
Nombre:<input id='i'/>
```

JS:

```
window.onbeforeunload = localStorage.setItem('x', document.getElementById('i').value);
```

Lo que quiero es que cuando el usuario salga de la pagina, lo que haya escrito en el input se guarde por si hay algún incidente y el usuario sale de la pagina o la recarga sin querer. El problema es, que, introduzco caracteres en el input y salgo de la pagina, en volver a entrar a la pagina, abro la consola y veo que localStorage.getItem('x') es "" habiendo introducido caracteres y habiéndose 'guardado' en localStorage.

¿He pasado algo por alto o me estoy confundiendo en algo?¿Como puedo solucionarlo y sobretodo porque me muestra esto la consola?

Answer (score 0):

Primero que nada hay que tener mucho cuidado con la información que se guarda en localStorage, no es para nada recomendado guardar información sensible en localStorage o en el sessionStorage.

Siguiendo con tu problema, el tema es que cuando ejecutas un window.onbeforeunload debes de pasarle una función con un return. Probablemente tu `localStorage.setItem('x', document.getElementById('i').value);` no esté guardando absolutamente nada.

Entonces la solución podría ser:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
  localStorage.setItem('x', document.getElementById('i').value);
  return 'whatever...';
};

const value = localStorage.getItem('x');
console.log(value)
```

Puedes también consultar esta liga --> https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload